# PHP recording the same array values when inserting forloop in mysql

Tags: php

When i'm submitting a data to my database it records the same value,
like for example
`

```
$prids: [1]
    $iprice: [60,190]
    ------------------
    TABLE DATA | VALUES
    prd_id (PM)| 16
    pr_id (FK) | 1
    iprice     | 60,60 (this thing record the same value)

<?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc())
    {
    echo
    "
    <td>
        <div class='input-group mb-3'>
            <input type='hidden' name='prids[]' value='".$_POST['view_id']."'>
            <span class='input-group-text'>₱</span>
            <input type='number' name='iprice[]' class='form-control' aria-label='Amount (to the nearest dollar)'>
            <span class='input-group-text'>.00</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    ";
    }
    if (isset($_POST['tests'])) 
    {
        $countitem = count($_POST['prids']);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $countitem; $i++) 
        {
            $sql = "UPDATE purchaserequest_details 
                    SET prd_itemBudget = ?
                    WHERE pr_id = ?;";
            $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($con);
            if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) 
            {
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ii",$_POST['iprice'][$i], $_POST['prids'][$i]);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            ?>
                <script>
                    window.location.href='budget-request.php?status=updated';
                </script>
            <?php
            }
        }
    }
  ?>`
```

i try the for loop method and it is recording in my table, but the attribute of 'iprice' to my table records the same value in the last array, i don't know what to do

Comment: When you `var_dump($_POST);` for debugging, does it contain the values that you expect?

Comment: You should prepare the statement before the loop, and then provide the differing values inside the loop. Or at least that's how I'd do it in PDO, I presume mysqli can do the same thing.

Comment: How does `prd_itemBudget` relate to the table view at the top of your post? Is it the same as `iprice`? Are you storing more than one value in the same column? Your table view suggests that you are, but your query is not. You shouldn't, if you are.

Comment: FYI have you filtered the POST values? Seems like an [XSS vulnerability](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/): One could inject any script they want by posting `view_id` with the value `'> <script src="https://example.com/malicious-script.js"> <input type="hidden" name='_`

Comment: Will that redirect inside the loop work immediately and stop execution of the second and subsequent iterations, or will it only do that if you `exit()` afterwards? I normally use a header redirect which I know will continue until the end of the script, I'm not sure if this version works differently. It seems a strange place to put it, in any case.

Comment: im still new in php sirs, my only problem is in the forloop method I'm trying to update the values in my purchaserequest_details but it ended up storing the same values that I input in iprice

this purchaserequest_details are the list of items in my table